# TreeView Get Node Value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview

Hi everyone I have weird Problem I have treeview in asp I fill it from Code With this Code :

```
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        If (row.Item(2).ToString().Equals("Open")) Then
            opn.ChildNodes.Add(New TreeNode(row.Item(1).ToString(), row.Item(0).ToString()))
        Else
            clos.ChildNodes.Add(New TreeNode(row.Item(1).ToString(), row.Item(0).ToString()))
        End If
    Next
    TreeViewDiscussions.Nodes.Clear()
    TreeViewDiscussions.Nodes.Add(opn)
    TreeViewDiscussions.Nodes.Add(clos)
```

and when TreeView Selected Node Changed I use this Event to Trigger another Event

```
    Protected Sub TreeViewDiscussions_SelectedNodeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TreeViewDiscussions.SelectedNodeChanged
    RaiseEvent DiscussionRequested(TreeViewDiscussions.SelectedNode.Value)
End Sub
```

The Problem is When I click on any node in the first Node I added ("opn" in this example) every thing works fine but if I click on any node in ("clos" in this example) the SelectedNode refere to None

any suggestion ?
and Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the Problem ;
when I initiated the TreeNode "opn" and "clos" I gave both of them the same Value "-1" and everything worked fine after changing them.